# How to display all x-variables on x-axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, variables, plot

I have tried looking online for ways to plot all of the x-variables on the x-axis of an R plot. However my problem is a too simple and its hard to understand more advance scripts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried using `scale_x_continuous` however I keep getting the error of object not found. I'm having trouble setting up my variables. Also, I don't even know if scale_x_continuous would work to help display all of my x- variables on the x-axis.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code or data. Copy and paste the code, and paste the output of `dput()` as part of your question.

Comment: `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = AveragDiveDepth$TagName)` should do it.